# ID to be taken from the parent side - Hibernate one-to-one relation

Tags: java, jpa

I have a class `UserAccountEntity` that is in a one-to-one relation with `UserEntity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_entity")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2059380022311094257L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = RandomAlphanumericIdGenerator.generatorName)
    @GenericGenerator(name = RandomAlphanumericIdGenerator.generatorName, strategy = "com.myproject.project.core.utils.RandomAlphanumericIdGenerator")
    private String id;

    public UserEntity() {}

}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_account_entity")
public class UserAccountEntity implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserEntity user;
}
```

Now I want to add another class `UserAccountActivityCode`, which should be in one and one relation with `UserAccountEntity`. What is confusing to me, is that the id of `UserAccountEntity` is generated in `UserEntity`. I wonder how I should define its id?

I created a class `UserAccountActivityCode`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User_account_activity_code")
public class UserAccountActivityCode implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = RandomAlphanumericIdGenerator.generatorName)
    @GenericGenerator(name = RandomAlphanumericIdGenerator.generatorName, strategy = "com.myproject.project.core.utils.RandomAlphanumericIdGenerator")
    private String id;

    public UserAccountActivityCode() {}

}
```

But how should I refer to it in the `UserAccountEntity` class and where does `UserAccountEntity` get id from in that case?

Update 1:
I took out `GeneratedValue` out of `UserAccountActivityCodeEntity`, and added `setUserId` to set it when saving:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_account_activity_code_entity")
public class UserAccountActivityCodeEntity {

    private final static int ACTIVITY_CODE_LENGTH = 6;

    @Id
    private String userId;

    private String acitivityCode;
    public UserAccountActivityCodeEntity(String id) {
        this.acitivityCode = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(ACTIVITY_CODE_LENGTH);
        this.userId = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getAcitivityCode() {
        return acitivityCode;
    }
    public void setAcitivityCode(String acitivityCode) {
        this.acitivityCode = acitivityCode;
    }

}
```

And I have the following code in my service layer:

```
    userAccount = new UserAccountEntity(username,
            passwordEncoder.encode(password));
    userAccount.setUser(new UserEntity());
    UserAccountActivityCodeEntity activityCode = new UserAccountActivityCodeEntity(userAccount.getId());
    userAccount.setActivityCode(activityCode);
    userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
```

Which leads to this error:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.myproject.project.core.entity.useraccount.UserAccountActivityCodeEntity
```

Comment: Why should it be different? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Different from `UserEntity`? If I add `private UserAccountActivityCode activityCode` to `UserAccountEntity`, then where does the id for `UserAccountEntity` come from? from `UserAccountActivityCode` or `UserEntity`

Comment: It comes from UserEntity, since you put the MapsId annotation on the `user` field, of type `UserEntity`.

Comment: But how should I put `UserAccountEntity` in one-to-one relation with `UserAccountEntity`? how should I define its id?

Comment: You already have a UserEntity with a OneToOne association with UserAccountEntity. And you already found how to use the ID of UserEntity inside UserAccountEntity. Now, if I understand correctly, you want to do exactly the same thing between UserAccountEntity and UserAccountActivityCode. So do it the exact same way: OneToOne, MapsId.

Comment: And I have to annotate both `UserEntity` and `UserAccountActivityCode` with `@GeneratedValue`?

Comment: In that case, I get this error: `Field 'activity_code_user_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: No. GeneratedValue means that an ID generator should be used to generate the ID. You don't want that. You want the ID to be taken out of the associated entity.

Comment: does it mean that I have to set the id manually for `UserAccountActivityCode` ? because I do it in the service layer and I get error. I updated my original post. (see Update 1)

Comment: Well, you don't have any OneToOne assciation with MapsId as you have in UserAccountEntity. If you want the ID of UserAccountActivityCode to be the same as UserAccountEntity, you need to have that, just as you got that in UserAccountEntity in order for its ID to be the same as UserEntity.

Comment: Can you post an answer an put the code you are explaining in it? it's a bit confusing here in the comments section. Do you mean I have to put the `@MapsId` in `UserAccountActivityCode`? Where should I put the `@OneToOne`? I want to be able to cascade Delete, etc from UserAccountEntity to `UserAccountActivityCode`.

Comment: Let's restart from the start: you have two entities, UserEntity and UserAccountEntity, linked by a OneToOne association with MapsId, which allows the ID of UserAccountEntity to be identical to the ID of UserEntity. Now you want the exact same thing to happen between UserAccountEntity and UserAccountActivityCodeEntity: the ID of UserAccountActivityCodeEntity should be identical to the ID of UserAccountEntity. So all you need to do is to use the same recipe: a OneToOne between the two entities, annotated with MapsId. I don't know how I could be clearer.

Comment: That's right. But the problem is that the parent in the relation between `UserEntity` and `UserAccountEntity` is `UserAccountEntity`. Which means the `MapsId` annotation and the `OneToOne` annotation are both in the `UserAccountEntity` and there is a pointer from this class to `UserEntity`. Now in the relation between `UserAccountEntity` and `UserAccountActivityCodeEntity` I still want `UserAccountEntity` to be the parent, but I don't want the id to come from `UserAccountActivityCodeEntity` because `UserAccountEntity` already gets its id from `UserEntity`

Comment: And there is no pointer from `UserAccountActivityCodeEntity` to `UserAccountEntity` to put the `MapsId` and `OneToOne` on the `UserAccountActivityCodeEntity` side, because I want the actions cascade from `UserAccountEntity` to `UserAccountActivityCodeEntity`

Comment: So make it a bidirectional OneToOne association.